# VHDL syntaxe error near if

Tags: vhdl

I'm a trying to find out the problem with this simple VHDL code. I'll be grateful if someone could help me.
**PS: I tried the code without the conditional block and it works :S !**

*The message error is : Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at Four_Bits_Adder.vhd(18) near text "if";  expecting ";", or an identifier ("if" is a reserved keyword), or "architecture"*

**The 4 bits adder code is :**

```
Library ieee;
Use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
Use ieee.numeric_std.all;
Use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;

entity Four_Bits_Adder is 
port(A,B:in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    S:out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
    Cout:out std_logic);
end Four_Bits_Adder;
architecture description of Four_Bits_Adder is 
begin 
S<= A+B;
if A(3)=1 then 
    if B(3)=1 then 
        Cout<=1;
        end if;
end if;     
end description;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `if` statement is a sequential statement, and from your usage should either be in a process statement or you should instead use a concurrent signal assignment statement.  It hardly seems complex enough for a process statement.

Concurrent assignment statement:

```
 Cout <= A(3) and B(3);
```

Note that concurrent assignment statement using an expression as the value in it's signal assignment can pass values other than '0' or '1'.

A different style of concurrent signal assignment statement could pass only binary representing enumeration values:

```
Cout <= '1'  when A(3) = '1' and B(3) = '1' else '0';
```

(Your `if` statement also appears to infer a latch and could be optimized as a constant '1').

Note also that your original `if` nested statements could be expressed with a BOOLEAN `and` which is a short-circuit operator taking the place of Ada's `if expression and then ...`.
Without one or more intervening statements following an `if` statement (including it's `end if`) there is no reason to nest `if` statements with different expressions.  The short-circuit operator would only evaluate the subsequent expression if the first expression evaluated true.

The form would be along the lines of

```
if A(3) = '1' and B(3) = '1' then
    Cout <= '1';
end if;
```

And could still only be used where a sequential statement is appropriate.

Note that std_logic requires enumeration values ('U', 'X', '0', '1',...) while `1` is a numeric value and would result in errors.

Comment: Thank you for your instructions and I appreciate your help!

Comment: If you're happy with the answer you can ask a different question for the next stumbling block.  Also see [Ask questions, get answers](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Answer (score 0):

Besides David's (correct) answer, note that if you are trying to make a 4-bit adder with Cout as the carry output, that process will not give the correct value. Consider A = "1111" and B = "0001". A(3) is '1' but B(3) is not, and the result is S = "0000" and Cout **should** be '1' but **is** '0'.