# VHDL Error 10500

Tags: vhdl

I have no idea why I am getting the following error.

> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at IR_REG.vhd(15) near text "if";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("if" is a reserved keyword), or a concurrent statement

Here is my code any help would be greatly appreciated

```
architecture behavior of IR_REG is
    signal temp: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    begin
    if IR_LD='1' then
        temp <= Input when clk = '1';
        IR <= temp when clk = '0';
    end if;
    end behavior;
```

Comment: An If statement is a sequential statement. An architecture body statement part would contain concurrent statements.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VHDL syntaxe error near if](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20435228/vhdl-syntaxe-error-near-if)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have an `if` statement inside an `architecture`. The key idea in `architecture` is the parallel execution of all statements There is no concept of *order*. For instance,

```
architecture Struct of Counter
  signal A1: bit;
  signal A2: bit;
begin
  A1 <= A2 and '1';
  A2 <= '1';
end Struct;
```

If this was a sequential block, `A1` would output `0` since `A2` takes its default value `0` initially. But VHDL's algorithm executes this block cleverly multiple times giving the *effect* that the two statements `A1 <= A2 and '1';` and `A2 <= '1';` happened simultaneously.

Hence if you run this code, you will get `A1` as `1` and `A2` as `1`.

Coming to your question, `if` is a *sequential* statement and cannot be inside a process due to its sequential nature. However, `when` can be used directly giving the effect of a **multiplexer**.

Looking at your code, it seems like you wanted to make a level sensitive latch. This is how you can do it.

```
architecture behavior of IR_REG is
    signal temp: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    begin
      process(IR_LD, Input, temp, clk)
      begin
        if IR_LD = '1' and clk = '1' then
          temp <= Input;
        end if;
        if IR_LD = '1' and clk = '0' then
          IR <= temp;
        end if;
      end process;
    end behavior;
```

---

This code will give the multiplexer effect, but it seems like you wanted to create a latch as shown above.

```
architecture behavior of IR_REG is
    signal temp: std_logic_vector(1 downto 0);
    begin
      temp <= Input when clk = '1' and IR_LD = '1' else "00";
      IR <= temp when clk = '0' and IR_LD = '1' else "00";
    end behavior;
```

Comment: From IEEE Std 1076-2008 Annex I Glossary: **block:** (A) The representation of a portion of the hierarchy of a design. A block is either an external block or an internal block. **internal block**: A nested block in a design unit, as defined by a block statement. **external block:** A top-level design entity that resides in a library and may be used as a component in other designs. There's an if statement, there is no if block.

Comment: Your 'key idea in `architecture`' is lacking from VHDL standard. The word 'simultaneous' is only used in a single place, a definition - ***protected type:** A type whose objects are protected from simultaneous access by more than one process.

Comment: Would the word *concurrent* work better here? Thank you for the comments

Comment: No concurrent doesn't help the accuracy of your assertion. See 11. Concurrent statements, 11.1 General - Concurrent statements are used to define interconnected blocks and processes that jointly describe the overall behavior or structure of a design. Concurrent statements execute asynchronously with respect to each other.

Comment: does it look better now?

Comment: 11.1 - *Within a given simulation cycle, an implementation may execute concurrent statements in parallel or in some order. The language does not define the order, if any, in which such statements will be executed. A description that depends upon a particular order of execution of concurrent statements is erroneous.*  Think signals - objects with past history, simulation cycles and projected output waveforms - a queue of future values causing signal events. Concurrency means the same simulation cycle not order of execution (sequence).